# login error into POS software

Tags: applications, google-play-store, kernel

I have downloaded Yalp Store successfully. It seems to be working, but I'm unable to log in into one of the software I downloaded. Do you know what this means... "Not allowed to start service intent [act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms(has extras)] without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" I get this when I try to log in into a Point Of Sale software I downloaded through your Yalp Store. I'll appreciate your insight.

Comment: We are not Yalp Store's staff, and the error message has nothing to do with Yalp Store either. The application is complaining about the inability to register via GCM for push notifications.

Comment: I appreciate your response but can you please direct me from where I can get resolved my problem. Actually, the error raised from a smart tv(Android)